# match multiple rows on same table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm making a faceted navigation with PHP and MySQL. I ran into a problem where I want to get the products with the specific filter.

Example structure and data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80065/4

Using the query from sqlfiddle I would get the results for one filter just fine.

For 2 filters the "query" that "would" work would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `attributes` WHERE ( `attribute_id` = '49' AND `text` = 'LED' ) AND ( `attribute_id` = '358' AND `text` = '1920x1080 (FullHD)' )
```

And of course this does not work.

The final query needs to give me the products ids. From the example it would be: 37743
37697

There are around 200,000 rows in the table.

I don't think JOIN would be a solution because it takes a lot of time and this will be used on a website faceted navigation.

Matching one row is not a problem but when I try to match two rows from the same table I can't get it to work.

**The filter needs to be usable with more than 2 WHERE's, the search for 2 attributes is just a example, I will need more than that**.

The returned rows need to contain the product_id which match my filter for 2 or more attributes.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would an `OR` between the two filters give you the desired result? side note: JOINs usually perform better than WHERE.

Comment: No. I need to match both attributes. And an `OR` would give me both LED and FullHD products.

Comment: you're requiring that every single record have multiple values for the same field, because you're tying your conditions together with `AND`. e.g. "your name is fred AND your name is mary AND your name is bart". You want `(x=y AND p=q) OR (x=z AND p=r) OR etc...`

Comment: That's is a contradiction: "search rows with the value of the field `attribute_id` is 49 **AND** 358"... No rows matched.

Comment: I believe he wants all products that have at least 1 row matching filter1 **and** at least 1 (not necessarily the same) matching filter2

Comment: dan08 is right `OR` will do the staff you need, and you keep `AND` within the brackets so attributes and text will matched in the right way. If you want  only the product ID then don't use `SELECT *`, select only your ID and also group by on it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, you are right but it will return all products that match atleast one attribute and I need to return only the ones that match them both. I solved this using group by, if you're interested in the final query look at my answer. Thank for commenting and helping!

Comment: Sorry TrueSkillZ, I didn't checked the answers. Your solution is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this on my own.

```
   SELECT `product_id` FROM `attributes`
   WHERE ( (`attribute_id` = '49' AND `text` = 'LED')
   OR
   (`attribute_id` = '358' AND `text` = '1920x1080 (FullHD)') )
   GROUP BY `product_id`
   HAVING count(*) = 2
```

This returns the ids of products that match both of my filters.

Working sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80065/35

Thanks for all the comments and answers!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the filter attributes are in array like this:

```
$attributes[] = array( 
    49  => 'LED', 
    358 => '1920x1080 (FullHD)' );
```

Then, make the filter:

```
$filterPieces = array();
foreach ( $attributes as $attId => $text ) {
    $filterPieces[] = sprintf(
        "(`attribute_id` = '%d' AND `text` = '%s')",
        $attId, $text );
}
$filter = implode( ' OR ', $filterPieces );
```

And finally the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `attributes` WHERE ( $filter )";
```

That's a solution without JOIN, in the front-end side.

In the code, I set `implode( ' OR ', $filterPieces )` for an OR logic connector, because AND produce a contradiction, and the result set is empty, EVER.

```
`attribute_id` = '49' AND `attribute_id` = '358'
```

No rows can satisfied the condition of two values at same time.

Comment: very nice answer. I've done something similar some time ago. It can be reformed in MySQL proc/func but the principle is the same although fetching all the results directly from thr DB should be a bit faster

Comment: Using `OR` is not a solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80065/27 It gives me all the rows possible with both attributes. From my question: "The final query needs to give me the products ids. From the example it would be: 37743 37697" and now I get everything.

Comment: Ok. Join is a bad solution because (conceivably) your table is not indexed. Try indexing for `product_id field` and back to Join solution. `SELECT * FROM attributes a JOIN attributes b USING( product_id ) WHERE ( a.attribute_id = '49' AND a.text = 'LED' ) AND ( b.attribute_id = '358' AND b.text = '1920x1080 (FullHD)' )`